# Android Studio Enter/backspace keys are not working

Tags: android-studio

I upgraded to Android studio 4.1.2 and now backspace and enter keys are not working in the terminal window. I haven't changed any keymaps. Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried several things and nothing worked. Only solution was to uninstall Android Studio and reinstalling it.